# Stop user from being able to write an outgoing SMS

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I've seen multiple entries stating it's not possible to block an **outgoing SMS**. My question is a little different. Is there any way to block the ability to **WRITE** the message itself from the default **SMS** application?

Basically a **round about way** of attempting the same thing.

To clarify, the purpose is to help prevent texting and driving. I can stop the incoming easy enough, but trying to find a way to prevent outgoing **SMS**. Now, I know you can block an "`outgoing broadcast`" per se... but I'm trying to stop the application the user would use to actually type the **outgoing SMS**

Comment: No, and why would you ever want to do so?

Comment: What does "write an outgoing SMS" mean? What does being the default SMS application have anything to do with this (at least, prior to Android 4.4)?

Comment: Well, regardless of the need, you can't.  You don't even know which app is being used (I have 3 SMS apps on my phone) and even if you did, there is no way your app can control what happens in the other app.